# Error is: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\MyPrj\App_Resources\Android'

Tags: angular2-nativescript

i'm get the following output when run tns run android in my project:

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
*                                                                                                               *
*  You are using the Legacy Workflow.                                                                           *
*                                                                                                               *
*  With the upcoming NativeScript 6.0 the Webpack workflow will become the only way of building apps.           *
*  More info about the reasons for this change and how to migrate your project can be found in the link below:  *
*  https://www.nativescript.org/blog/the-future-of-building-nativescript-apps                                   *
*                                                                                                               *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *


Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\MyPrj\App_Resources\Android'.
Stopping tsc watch
Stopping webpack watch
```

`tns --version` gives me 5.4.2.

also I'm trying to upgrade all modules. even installed nativescript-dev-webpack
but the output is same:

```
ERROR in [copy-webpack-plugin] unable to locate 'D:\MyPrj\App_Resources/Android' at 'D:\MyPrj\App_Resources/Android'
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

Update your nativescript cli with latest version using **npm i -g nativescript** and create a new project using nativescript sidekick and try to again run the project.